# Android: View with 0 height and memory consumption

Tags: android, view, height, visible, zero

Let's say for example that I have a view and I have an algorithm that causes the View's height to become 0 when it scrolls off screen.  Does this View still consume the same amount of memory as it would if it were full size? I guess I should ask the same question for View.INVISIBLE or View.GONE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - a `View` is an `Object` and as long as any `Object` exists (whether it's a UI object or not) it uses exactly the same amount of memory. At the point an `Object` in an OOP environment ceases to exist (it's destroyed / de-referenced and garbage collected) then it uses no memory at all. There isn't very much in-between.

Making a UI object invisible or reducing its size in width/height to 0 will simply mean the GPU won't have to process it in the same way regardless of whether it is on screen or off.

Comment: That's interesting.  My co-worker implemented a scrolling grid in c# and in his main loop to scroll the grid, he makes the size of anything not visible become 0.  He told me that he reduced the memory consumption of his app from 1.4GB to 600MB.  Maybe c# has some optimizations that Android doesn't have?

Comment: Without knowing your co-worker's code it's hard to comment but I'm slightly sceptical about his claims. Depending on the system he is developing for (perhaps without a GPU and rendering being software rather than hardware dependent) then it may be possible. The point is that in any OO environment, an `Object` takes as much space as it needs whether it's an Android object or a POJO whether it's visible or not. I program in C# for Windows and I can't think of anything about it that would significantly change its ability to manage memory much better than Java for Android.

Comment: HMm..then I'm thinking the other way is to remove the view(s).  But that would trigger the garbage collector, which would lead to stuttering during animation/scrolling?